# access routing parameters from another module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a Core module without a routing module and a feature module with a routing module in my application. In a component of my feature module I have access to routing params by using this in the constructor:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  console.log("params['searchTerm']");
  console.log(params['searchTerm']);
  this.searchTerm = params['searchTerm'];
});
```

Now in a component of my Core module I would like to access the params as well by using the code above. Since the routes are defined in the feature modules routing module I just get undefined when I try to access the params.

How could i achieve to access the params?

Comment: Try to Import the  routing module of the feature module in the core module

Comment: still undefined

Comment: can you put more code, the core module, feature module, routing module, and your component please

Comment: I think it's not possible. To activate your feature module, the routing must match the path to your feature module. If you want to get the same data in core module, you have to define the same path for core module (or define a service that will send params from feature to core). Could you provide your routing module ?

Comment: True. Thanks for the advice. I will go with the service approach. Provide it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the possible solutions:

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
  router.events.subscribe((e) => {
    let currentRoute = this.route.root;
    while (currentRoute.children[0] !== undefined) {
      currentRoute = currentRoute.children[0];
    }
    if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      // you can do it for exact phase
      console.log(currentRoute.snapshot.params);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same situation. Routing is defined in a feature module and core module's layout component has access to params. It works! Make sure that you:

1. import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router'; in core module
2. Inject  'private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute' in core component constructor.